# KVM for two Macs? to share one cinema display and keyboard between a Mac Pro and a Macbook

Tags: mac, kvm-switch

I have a Mac Pro and a Macbook Pro. I have a cinema display plugged into the pro most of the time, and a custom clacky keyboad... occasionally I want to "dock" my mac book in there instead to use the display an keyboard. (my mice are wireless anyway so dont need to plug nor share those)

I want a KVM switch that supports 2 Macs, each getting a Mini Display Port connection and USB keyboard connection? Any recommendations?

Comment: @Juhele Google suggestion lead me to find the main 2 Mini DisplayPort KVM that shows up on the first page of Google is the Atlona, but that reviews poorly. [link](http://www.mymac.com/2010/08/atlona-2-x-1-mini-displayport-kvm-switch)  Does anyone have another recommendation other than the Atlona?

Answer (score 0):

As I googled a little, I found some, but with very high price. Maybe easier and cheaper could be to uses standard KVM for DVI together with Mini DisplayPort to DVI Adapter. Does the big display have any other ports than mini displayport?

Comment: The Cinema Display I have only has Mini DisplayPort connector. So I'm looking for a KVM switch for Mini DisplayPort recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

[Does this KVM from Kanex work?](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&sku=817408&gclid=CjwKEAjwpuSvBRDSkaes4OasuEESJACfwIc_0Orx9EaAZBYDnZ-j-TfAS4niXCVNfz1UbWWEzkgYjRoCshbw_wcB&is=REG&m=Y&A=details&Q=)

Comment: Can you expand upon what this does? I don't think this is spam (I make big-ticket camera purchases from B&H, and your link indicates that you got there via a Google ad, with no affiliate parameters) but this answer needs to provide a description of the product.